# How many turbine powered aircraft are in the air at any given time?

Tags: turbine, datasets

I know there are a lot of statistics about how many planes are in the air on average, but not all aircraft flying are turbine-driven. How may turbojet, turbofan, and turboprop aircraft, on average, are in the air at any given moment?

Comment: It may be impossible to answer as many smaller aircraft may not be tracked or recorded. How precise does the number have to be?

Comment: You may try to search in IATA statistics like [these ones](https://www.skybrary.aero/bookshelf/books/3049.pdf)

Comment: @user39178 Right now, Flightradar24 is tracking **10,582**: https://www.flightradar24.com/37.46,126.44/14 Are they all turbine powered? Probably. Are they every turbine powered aircraft? Probably not. But I don't know where you will get a better answer than that...

Comment: Hi @fooot. I believe the comment above answers without being an opinion, and uses a reference, what do you think? Regards

Comment: @Penguin most of the traffic is turbine powered, but definitely not all. And it probably doesn't include everything. But you're right that it's probably a good guess.